# Image to not cause a row size change

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a simple `Grid` with three columns.  In one of these rows, I have (in column order): A `TextBlock`, a `TextBox`, and a `Button`.  The `Button` contains an `Image` for it's content.

My issue is that the `Image` always sizes to display it's full content which enlarges the button.  I don't care what size the image's source is; I want the `Button` to be the same size as the row already is due to the `TextBlock` and the `TextBox`.  I don't want to specify a hard coded value for the image size. That's not the point.  If a user's theme and/or font changes, the `Grid` row should still work as expected and the `Button` should always be the correct size.

I've tried a `ViewBox`, all sorts of alignment properties and bindings.  No luck.  Any ideas anyone?

```
   <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0" x:Uid="RONumber" />
   <TextBox x:Name="tbRO" InputScope="Number" MaxLength="8" Grid.Column="1" Margin="4" />
   <Button x:Name="btnSearch" Click="Search_Click" Grid.Column="2">
      <Image Source="Long Source Removed For Readability" />
   </Button>
```

In the image below you can see the TextBox and to the right the Button with the Image inside it.  Right below it is another TextBox which is correctly sized.  And if I remove the button the top TextBox sizes the same.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here's the answer.  Because the elements are in the same row the XAML is not working.  The binding I had made (before I even posted this question) to the ActualHeight always was 0.  I instead bound the MaxHeight of the button to the ActualHeight of a random TextBox on another area of the screen.  This worked.